# X509Store unable to load certificate by thumbprint

Tags: .net, .net-core, certificate, x509certificate2

In .NET Core I am trying to load certificate by thumbprint via X509Store object. Code looks like:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "thumbprint here", false);
```

I always get empty collection of certs. I have found lot of SO question where problem was invisible character at the end or beginning or thumbprint. This is not my case I have checked whitespace symbols and also I have rather applied this to thumbprint in code:

```
Regex.Replace(thumbprint.ToUpper(), @"[^0-9A-F]+", string.Empty)
```

When I enumerate store.Certificates my cetrificate is correctly present. I can easily match certificate by

```
foreach (var certificate in certificates)
{
   if (certificate.Thumbprint == "thumbprint here".ToUpper())
   { ... }
}
```

Anyone know why standard X509FindType.FindByThumbprint search doesn't work?

Comment: Does it show up if you pass `false` in the last argument? If so, then the most likely answer is the cert is expired, or your computer can't chain it to a root authority it trusts.

Comment: CA isn't valid that's right. But I actually have isValid argument set to false and it doesn't show up.